# Error in my Pokeapi (android studio and java)

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.package-info found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelField found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl$1 found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelUtils found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$1 found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$ParcelException found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$FieldBuffer found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelize found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version' from inputs:
> - C:\Users\PC VISION.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1f055fb15f803ff3d112130cf11912db\transformed\localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0\jars\classes.jar
> - C:\Users\PC VISION.gradle\caches\transforms-3\46cf5eaed2a25632fee345e1e311a451\transformed\localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar
> Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
> https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
> for more information

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this error in the past and I solved it with below steps.

1. Open gradle.properties files.
2. Now add this two lines

   `android.useAndroidX=true`

   `android.enableJetifier=true`
3. Now just Rebuild your project and you are done.

**Note** -  If your gradle.properties files already has `android.useAndroidX=true` inside then Just add `android.enableJetifier=true` and rebuild your project.

Hope it works for you too.

**What do these two properties do**, so according to [**documentation**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx#:%7E:text=Using%20androidx%20libraries%20in%20your%20project,-See%20Migrating%20to&text=properties%20file.,if%20it%20is%20not%20specified.) of android:

**android.useAndroidX:** When this flag is set to true, the Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

**android.enableJetifier:** When this flag is set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX dependencies by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.